# how to bind imageview to array index mvvm javafx

Tags: java, javafx, mvvm, imageview, bind

I'm currently trying to program BlackJack in JavaFX and I use ImageViews to display the cards. I have a player model which has a LinkedHashMap of Strings and cards from my Card class.

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Card> cards = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

The String always looks like "ACE-CLUB" or "SIX-HEART", because my imported images are also named like that [("ACE-CLUB.png")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1kWn.png).

Now, I don't know how I should bind the ImageView *playerCardOne* to the first position of the LinkedHashMap. I thought about making an array which only stores the Strings of the LinkedHashMap but then I'd still don't know how I bind an ImageView. I thought it may look something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
playerCardOne.imageProperty().bind(new Image("/cards/" + vm.getPlayerCard(0) + ".png"));
```

The method getPlayerCard(0) returns the String which is stored at the index of the number in the brackets (0).

I hope someone can help? It's my first time using MVVM and making a more complex program using JavaFX. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your question, you need to make `cards` observable first:

```java
ObservableMap<String, Card> cards = FXCollections.observableMap(new LinkedHashMap<>());
```

Then you can create a `Binding` that always returns the first item in your map like this:

```java
ObjectBinding<Image> firstImageBinding = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Card>> iterator = cards.entrySet().iterator();
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        return new Image("/cards/" + iterator.next().getKey() + ".png");
    }
    return null;
}, cards);
```

Finally, you can bind it to an `Image` property:

```java
playerCardOne.imageProperty().bind(firstImageBinding);
```

Although this might work as you expect, I believe you can make it better.

First, I don't know how you implemented `Card` class, but anytime you need a fixed set of constants, you should use enums:

Suit class:

```java
enum Suit { 
    CLUB, DIAMOND, HEART, SPADE 
}
```

Rank class:

```java
enum Rank { 
    ACE, DEUCE, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING 
}
```

Card class:

```java
public class Card {
    private final Suit suit;
    private final Rank rank;

    public Card(Suit suit, Rank rank) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public Rank getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Card card = (Card) o;
        return suit == card.suit &&
                rank == card.rank;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(suit, rank);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s %s", suit, rank);
    }
}
```

Now, you can get an `Image` for a `Card` without the need to use a `Map<String, Card>`:

```java
public Image getImageForCard(Card card) {
    String url = String.format("/cards/%s-%s.png", card.getRank(), card.getSuit());
    return new Image(url);
}
```

If you are always interested in the image of the first card in a `List<Card>`, you can get it like this:

```java
ObservableList<Card> cards = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

ImageView playerCardOne = new ImageView();
ObjectBinding<Image> firstImageBinding = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> 
        cards.isEmpty() ? null : getImageForCard(cards.get(0)), cards);
playerCardOne.imageProperty().bind(firstImageBinding);

cards.add(new Card(Suit.CLUB, Rank.ACE));
// playerCardOne's image is now /cards/ACE-CLUB.png

cards.add(0, new Card(Suit.HEART, Rank.SIX));
// playerCardOne's image is now /cards/SIX-HEART.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I will be of much help but I did something similar with only one image like this:

```
Bindings.bindBidirectional(imageView.imageProperty(),manager.getCurrentImage());
```

with the image of manager being

```
public final ObjectProperty<Image> currentImage = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
```

so in your case i suppose it would be easier to directly put for every card an Object element
then go with

```
playerCardOne.imageProperty().bind(vm.getPlayerCard(0).getImage())
```